# r XLconnect equivalent to sqlFetch

Tags: sql, r, xlconnect

I have an old 32 bit snippet

```
xl <- odbcConnectExcel("c:/myFile.xls")
data <- sqlFetch(xl, "flowers$")
```

but now I have 64 bit machine and can't use odbcConnectExcel. I have read that I should use XLconnect, BUT how do I use sqlFetch with XLconnect? i.e How do I rewrite the second line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

library(XLConnect)

xl <- loadWorkbook("c:/myfile.xls")

data <- readWorksheet(xl,"flower")   #assumes the worksheet name is "flower"

Answer (score 0):

Try odbcConnectExcel2007 and make sure that the MS Office that you have, the R version are all 64-bit.